# Order Dictionary by second element of Key

Tags: c#, .net, sorting, dictionary, key

I'm searching for an easy way to make a (sorted) dictionary for the following data with c#.

Person:

| ID | Name |
| --- | --- |
| n4 | Anne |
| n2 | Ben |
| n3 | Ben |
| n1 | Cesar |

Order:

| PersonID | Description |
| --- | --- |
| n4 | Salami |
| n4 | Ananas |
| n3 | Banana |
| n2 | Apple |
| n1 | Banana |
| n1 | Cheese |

For each Person (ID is unique, Name not) I should have all the Orders.
I have to **display all the rows ordered by Person.Name**, like:

- Anne: Salami, Ananas
- Ben: Apple
- Ben: Banana
- Cesar: Banana, Cheese

The Values of the dictionary are not the problem, but the Key.
My first approach was to use the Person.ID as key:

```
Dictionary<string, Queue<Order>> lastOrders = new Dictionary<string, Queue<Order>>();
```

But then I have the problem, that the dicionary is not ordered (when I take a SortedDictionary it would only be ordered by ID instead of Name). That means in a foreach loop I have to get the Person.Name for each key and create a new ordered list (?) and use this in a new foreach loop.

Because I need the Person.ID (as unique identifier) and Person.Name (for sorting) another option could be:

```
SortedDictionary<KeyValuePair<string, string>, Queue<Order>> lastOrders;
```

I think the first string must be the unique ID and the second the Name?
But then, the dictionary is ordered again first by the ID instead the Name?

Because the PersonIDs never change (it's not a good example above, the Persons are static, the number of Persons can not change when the application is running) and only the Values of the dictionary changes, I think it is better to use a sorted dictionary (or to sort it once) than to sort it before every use (display).
Maybe I'm thinking too far. Do you have a better idea? Thanks.

Comment: You can make that dictionary sortable by Name with a custom comparer function. Like this: `var persons = new SortedDictionary<Person, Queue<Order>>(Comparer<Person>.Create((p1, p2) => p1.Name.CompareTo(p2.Name)));`

Comment: @AvoNappo: thank you very much! I'll accept this as answer if you post it.I make it now with ` = new SortedDictionary<KeyValuePair<string, string>, Queue<Order>>(Comparer<KeyValuePair<string, string>>.Create( ( p1, p2 ) => p1.Value.CompareTo(p2.Value) ) )`
becaus I have to hold the dictionary in memory and I think this uses less space.

Comment: Ok, posted as answer. Out of curiosity, why use Queue<T> to hold orders, instead of List<T>?

Comment: @AvoNappo: I always have to get the last 10 inserted "orders" per "person" (in reality the persons are practically constand, and a person typically inserts a new order every few minutes) and I thought it's easier to update (en-/dequeue) a queue than to remove the first item of a list and add an item (and perhaps easier to understand for this use case and has better performance, but I'm a newbie...).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From comment:

```
var persons = new SortedDictionary<Person, Queue<Order>>(Comparer<Person>.Create((p1, p2) => p1.Name.CompareTo(p2.Name)));
```